# url Encoding in ios

Tags: iphone, url, encoding, urlencode

I get a link from server to image  has already been Encoding so it comes with %20
But sometimes I get a code include Hebrew characters, so I need to do Encoding agian , With the above code:

But after my Encoding i get in response that % 20 change to % 2520

```
static CFStringRef charsToEscape = CFSTR("&=");

    + (NSString *)escapeStringByAddingPercentEscapes: (NSString*) string {

        return [(NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                                                    (CFStringRef)string,
                                                                    NULL,
                                                                    charsToEscape,
                                                                    CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)) autorelease];
    }
```

i tried to add % to  charsToEscape like this:

static CFStringRef charsToEscape = CFSTR("&=%");

but it did not help.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *urlString = @"----YOUR URL HERE----";
[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is good if I did not get the Hebrew characters in the link.

But I found the solution , I just sent the % in the parameter legalURLCharactersToBeEscaped

now i use in the function like this:

```
static CFStringRef charsToEscape = CFSTR("&=");
static CFStringRef charsUnchanged = CFSTR("%");

    + (NSString *)escapeStringByAddingPercentEscapes: (NSString*) string {

        return [(NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                                                    (CFStringRef)string,
                                                                    charsUnchanged,
                                                                    charsToEscape,
                                                                    CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)) autorelease];
    }
```

thanks